# Simple question on field extensions of separably closed fields

Tags: abstract-algebra, field-theory, extension-field

Let $k$ be a separably closed field, say $k=\mathbb{C}$.

Is it true that any finite field extension of $k$ is separably closed?

Comment: $\mathbb{C}$ does not admit any finite field extensions. Moreover, I think separably closed is not really a helpful concept in characteristic 0, as every such field is perfect.

Answer (score 1):

Let $L/k$ be a finite extension, then for any finite extension $F/L$, $F/k$ is purely inseparable, thus by the multiplicativity of separable degrees, $F/L$ is also purely inseparable, thus $L$ is separably closed.